# passing variables through page

Tags: php, mysql

I have represented data in tabular form with no problem. But when i click the delete button i want the $id i.e. row[0] of my database to pass to another page delete_user_post.php where i can capture this value of $id using $_REQUEST. When i echo $id it shows its associated id. But i am not able to pass that value in next page.what have i done wrong??
`

```
<tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>

          <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="controls"> 

                <?php $id = $row[0];
                echo $id;
                ?>

                <a href="delete_user_post.php?roomid=$id" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Delete</a> 
                </td>   



          </div>
          </tr>  
          <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

My user_delete_post.php looks like this:

```
<?php
      include ('include/DB_Functions.php');      
      $id =$_REQUEST['roomid'];     
      // sending query
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM room_tb WHERE roomID=$id") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*()` functions. Use PDO and MySQLi instead.

Comment: Is it just me or you're not really printing the $id in the link's href attribute? use the <?php ?> tags and echo it properly.
You should also avoid just taking request parameters from the user and perform SQL commands with it. It makes a security opening called SQL Injection. For further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: On a side note, since you are explicitly supplying the variables to the target page in the URL, consider using GET to retrieve them in `delete_user_post.php`, instead if REQUEST. The REQUEST method hunts for the variable in the GET, POST as well as Cookie arrays and can have unwanted repercussions which may be hard to debug, in case a variable similar to $id is present in any of those.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're not actually `echo`ing the `$id`.

Replace your `a` tag with this:

```
<a href="delete_user_post.php?roomid=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Delete</a>
```

**Also** please look up [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as a replacement for `mysql_`

**Also** think long and hard about if you really want [unescaped and unverified](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) `IDs` to be deleted from your database.

Comment: You should be mentioning PDO to give the OP a choice

Answer (score 2):

Try to put $id in php tags like,

```
<a href="delete_user_post.php?roomid=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Delete</a>
```